# SQLite Join Table Mapping

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I have a database with multiple Tables. Todo and Task.

The relation between is  Todo  1 -> n Tasks

Now I join the table with this query:

```
Select * from todo to
Left join task ta
ON to.id = ta.todo_fk;
```

When I have 1 Todo and 10 tasks, the result of the Cursors shows

10 (the same) todos with 10 task.

How can I map the Tasks in a list from the cursor?

```
public class Todo {
    public String title;
    public List<Task> taks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can do just like this to assign cursor value to List

```
    taks = List<Task>();     
    if (cursor!=null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    do{
        Task t = new Task();
        String todo = cursor.getString("column_name1").toString();
        String task = cursor.getString("column_name2").toString();
        t.setTask(todo);
        t.setTask(task);
        taks.add(t); 
    }while(c.moveToNext());
   }
```

Comment: Ok and how assgin that to the todo.  It is possible with one time looping the cursor?.. so i must show if the tasks assign to the todo